# Helper app location

Tags: helper, mac-app-store

Where is the best location to put a Mac helper app inside the bundle of another app? I can't find a definitive answer to this (including what is acceptable for the Mac App Store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for any bundle, you can create a folder named `Support` inside the directory:

```
XYZ.app/
    Info.plist
    XYZ
    Icon.png
    Support/
        SomeHelper
```